# Webpage not found on mobile devices - 404

Tags: .htaccess, mobile, http-status-code-404, web-deployment

I was about to set up a website and have now uploaded it to the server.

While there are no problems displaying the page on desktop devices, a 404 error is issued on mobile devices.
If I open the page in desktop view on mobile, the page is displayed.

[diemoebelbewegung.de](https://diemoebelbewegung.de)

The site does not use wordpress or similar CMS.
I am not using an .htaccess file at the moment, could this be a problem?

I'm a complete beginner in server settings and just uploaded all the files.
The site should be fully responsive.

---

**Edit:**

Found out that there has to be some kind of redirection of mobile devices to a subfolder /m .

So for now I just made a second copy of all files in this subfolder m.
This solves my problem for now but not on long term.

Any ideas where this redirection of mobile devices to the subfolder m could come from? Or how to avoid having to store the files twice on the webserver.

**Edit**

May this be some serverside default redirective? And is there maybe a method to overwrite this with an .htaccess rule?

Another idea would be to redirect only Desktop devices to the subfolder /m

**Edit**

@MrWhite 's answer solves the problem provisional:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Required for the canonical redirect, if the trailing slash is omitted.
RewriteBase /

# Redirect any "direct" requests for the /m subdirectory back to the root
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^m(/.*|$) $1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite all requests to the /m subdirectory (if not already)
RewriteRule !^m/ m%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Still it is not clear why this 'redirection' to /m occurs at all.

Comment: Works OK for me on mobile. (?)

Comment: @MrWhite See edit

Comment: "The site does not use wordpress or similar CMS" - Is the site completely handcoded by you? Any redirect to `/m` would be in your application code (or `.htaccess` - but you say you don't have a `.htaccess` file). However, I'm not seeing a redirect to `/m`, so maybe this is perhaps cached on your device?

Comment: I used Bootstrap to code the site. Yes i don't use any .htaccess. I deleted the subfolder m for now and i cant reach the site with mobile device...

Comment: i can repoduce this even in browser developer tools -> select any mobile device

Comment: OK, I was able to reproduce this behaviour later (presumably after you removed the files in `/m`? Although as I write this it is working again, so presumably you put the files back?). However, there was no "external redirect" - there's no change to the URL. How did you find out it was "redirecting" to `/m`? If there is any redirect then it would seem to be internal to your server (ie. an "internal rewrite"). If there is any redirect at all it must be coming from your application code somewhere? Or are you using some kind of proxy/CDN? Servers don't do that sort of redirect by default.

Comment: yes i put the files back. I found out by looking at the backedup files of the old page where there was a mobile page located in that subfolder /m. I deleted all files and uploaded the new page (which should be fully responsive and worked without problems as github page  https://fischbroetchen.github.io/mb/

Comment: The other issue is you now (potentially) have a duplicate content problem because the `/m` subdirectory is publicly available. Include a canonical meta tag in your pages to workaround this or a `robots.txt` file and prevent crawling of the `/m` subdirectory.

Comment: I want to avoid having duplicate content overall, so changes in the website (I'm using a flat-file cms) won't need to be done twice... I was trying to redirect from the /m folder to the root directory, which resultet in a redirection loop ( /m/m/m/m...). One way would be to redirect only desktop devices to the /m directory and have all the content stored in /m. Is there a way to do so via .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One way would be to redirect only desktop devices to the `/m` directory and have all the content stored in `/m`. Is there a way to do so via `.htaccess`?

In theory this should be possible as a "workaround". However, finding where this "redirect" (or rather "internal rewrite") is occurring and fixing that would be the preferred method.

As noted, this does appear to be an *internal rewrite* to the `/m` subdirectory, not strictly a "redirect" (which implies an *external* 3xx HTTP redirect). There is no change in the URL. This is probably conditional based on the `User-Agent` string.

Anyway, to implement this in `.htaccess` for *all* requests (ie. desktop as well) then you can do something like the following using mod_rewrite in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite all requests to the /m subdirectory (if not already)
RewriteRule !^m/ m%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This rewrites all requests to the `/m` subdirectory, so you only have one code base to maintain, ie. the one in the `/m` subdirectory.

We can also "correct" any direct requests for the `/m` subdirectory and redirect back to the root, preventing a potential *duplicate content* issue with search engines. The following directive would need to go *before* the above rewrite (after the `RewriteEngine` directive).

```
# Required for the canonical redirect, if the trailing slash is omitted.
RewriteBase /

# Redirect any "direct" requests for the /m subdirectory back to the root
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^m(/.*|$) $1 [R=301,L]
```

The *condition* that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures we only target direct requests by the client and not rewritten requests.

The `$1` backreference in the *substitution* contains the URL-path less the `m/` prefix (ie. the subdirectory). In situations where `/m` is requested without a trailing slash, the substitution string would otherwise be empty - hence the need for the `RewriteBase` directive to avoid a malformed redirect. (Alternatively, the `RewriteRule` directive could be modified to `RewriteRule ^test(?:/(.*)|$) /$1 [R=302,L]` to avoid the need for `RewriteBase`).

IMPORTANT: Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

Clear your browser cache before testing.

#### Summary

With all the directives in-place.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Required for the canonical redirect, if the trailing slash is omitted.
RewriteBase /

# Redirect any "direct" requests for the /m subdirectory back to the root
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^m(/.*|$) $1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite all requests to the /m subdirectory (if not already)
RewriteRule !^m/ m%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

*Aside:* I notice you are not currently canonicalising the www subdomain? ie. www vs non-www.

---

**UPDATE:** An alternative method for the canonical redirect above to try:

```
# Redirect any "direct" requests for the /m subdirectory back to the root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/m(/|$)
RewriteRule ^m(/.*|$) $1 [R=301,L]
```

`THE_REQUEST` server variable contains the first line of the request headers as sent from the client. And should not change when the request is *rewritten*. However, if the request is being *proxied* then this probably won't work either.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i tried to set up the htaccess like you said, but it is still not working.
For dektop devices i now gt redirected to the /m directory (everything as planned) but for mobile devices i receive an "redirection error.."

Comment: I cant find any settings referring to an internal rewrite. Any idea where this could come from? I'll try to get into customer support, but last time they just said my website is not optimized for mobile...

Comment: What is the nature of the "redirection error" (ie. from/to)? Presumably this is an endless "redirect loop"? Try removing the "redirect" above (ie. the two `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` - `R=301` lines) - this isn't necessary for the site to work, it was just to resolve the duplicate content issue, but this can be resolved in other ways (and may not be an issue anyway).

Comment: Do you have access to the server config / VirtualHost container? What kind of hosting is this? The network response appears to be coming from `Apache/2.4.46 (Unix)`. To clarify, there are no front-end proxies / load balancers? "they just said my website is not optimized for mobile" - what did they mean by this? (Your site is _responsive_; it looks "optimized" to me.)

Comment: Yes it was due to the redirect loop. I removed the middle lines, and now it works with content in the /m directory only. I searched all the front-end options but couldnt find any matching your description. There are some DNS settings i dont know of, but i dont think this has to do with this, as i already resetted those options. I don't know how to acces the server config, as i alreay stated Im not an expert in this area. I have acces to the shell via ssh, but i don't know where to look at. Lots of commands arent working either.

Comment: I found a "Mobile_Detect.php" aswell as a "Mobile_Detect.json" in the old website files. Could this script still be running somewhere on the server? How can i detect running scripts or processes ( i tried ps, but command is not found)

Comment: Presumably the "old website files" are moved elsewhere? Although I don't see how this would be called unless you are explicitly calling this in your code? If you rename those files does it change anything?

Comment: the files are backed up locally, there are no copies on the server at all....

Comment: In that case I don't see how those files could have anything to do with this. The fact that you were seeing a redirect loop (with that redirect in place) would seem to suggest that  Apache is not "rewriting" the request for mobile, but could perhaps be "proxied" in the server config? But that seems a bit odd if you don't have access to the server config.

Comment: hmm i could try reaching the customers support again.. Is the current setup somehow bad for SEO or page speed/ performance? Or can I just leave it like that? I don't have duplicte content anymore and the site is shown on every device...

Comment: With the rewrite in place there is nothing bad in terms of SEO or performance... this is an acceptable working solution... all requests are internally rewritten to the `/m` subdirectory, so you just have one copy of the site to maintain. Make sure you set a `rel="canonical"` link element in the HTML source to protect against duplicate content issues. Although "duplicate content" shouldn't be a problem anyway providing there are no old backlinks to the `/m` directory.

Comment: I set up your modified solution and, as far as i can see, it is working.

Comment: That's good! Curious though why the earlier redirect didn't work - it would seem the "mobile" rewrite to `/m` probably isn't a "rewrite". (?) Just curious, I realise the server is declaring itself as Apache but is this perhaps a LiteSpeed server? (LiteSpeed is a "drop-in" replacement for Apache and is commonly used in shared server environments. However, it has some significant differences. One difference is that `REDIRECT_STATUS` is not set on error responses, although that shouldn't necessarily apply here.)